# Jenkins - Trigger/call builds on other projects - Help needed on sending multi-line String parameter

Tags: jenkins, plugins, parameters, parameter-passing, multiline

I have a 2 Jenkins job:

1. projectA - will run periodically for latest builds and updates a text file to trigger yes. When the trigger is set to YES, it will trigger the downstream projectB with multiple kinds of parameters passed as Key=Value format
2. projectB - has multiple parameters - including Boolean, String, Extended Choice & Multi-line parameters.
   [projectB - Parameters page on a normal execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYSKC.png)

So when the projectA triggers projectB, all parameters have been passed successfully. For the Multi-line parameter, only the first line value is passed & discarding all subsequent lines.

> ```
> WaitTime=900
> DBCheck=true
> Snmpwalk=true
> TcpPortScanner=false
> CLI_DisplayOutput="show 1
> show 2
> show 3"
> ```

Upon checking the Parameters page on this triggered execution, It displays only single line text box instead of Multi line text box.

[projectB - Parameters page which is triggered by projectA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdhTh.png)

P.S.

1. Wait time might be different. Just captured random build run.
2. Instead of getting a multi line string, the parameter was single-line string

Br,
Jagan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is very late, and many could have solved the problem. I would like to highlight what I have done during the issue occurred time.

As explained, I used Multiline input (in Configure)

[image]

and the execution Parameter listed as below with multiple show commands (during Run)

[image]

I used another plugin to write this content as a file in my workspace during my Build Step (in Configure)

[image]

I also made sure that the content is successfully passed and file created at my execution

[image]

Now my device could read the contents one by one and executes it.

Answer (score 0):

Use backslash `\` at the end of the line.

E.g., in the 'Predefined build parameters' section you can define

```
PARAMETER_A = value-of-the-param-a
PARAMETER_B =  \
value-of-the-param-b
```

Comment: Hi @D.Naumovich,
Thanks for the comment. But the values for Parameter_B is taken as a single-line text value instead of Multi-line text. I needed an input for a Multi-line text. 

I have to send multiple show commands to my device wherein if I use with \ all the show commands were sent in a single line as "show 1 show 2 show 3" which eventually failed in my device.

Comment: It doesn't work for me ether. Does anyone have a fix/workaround for that?